# Scalatest: how to combine BeforeAndAfterEach with "should behave like"

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a set of tests all of which require same code before each test, for this purpose I happily use BeforeAndAfterEach. I need to perform the set of tests a few times with different settings of the fixtures. To perform the tests several times I use test sharing with "should behave like" from FlatSpecLike. However, I don't see an elegant way to combine "should behave like" with BeforeAndAfterEach.

Currently I use the Tag-based method presented below. Quite ugly.

*Question: is there a more elegant way to perform a set of tests under different settings that are used before each test in the set.*

```
class TestSpec() extends FlatSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterEachTestData {

// have to invent a tag with a name for each object of Settings
  val TagNamePrefix = "MySettingsTag"
  case object NormalTag extends Tag(TagNamePrefix+"Normal")
  case object SpecialTag extends Tag(TagNamePrefix+"Special")
// and put them into a map by name
  var settingsMap: String => Settings = Map (
    NormalTag.name -> Settings(0, 0, someGlobalNormalObject),
    SpecialTag.name -> Settings(10, 10, someGlobalSpecialObject)
  )

  override def beforeEach(testData: TestData) {
    val s: Settings = retrieveSettings(testData)
    // some code here depending on the settings
    super.beforeEach(testData)
  }

  /** the ugly way to retrieve settings in beforeEach */
  private def retrieveSettings(testData: TestData): Settings = {
    val tags = testData.tags.filter(_.startsWith(TagNamePrefix))
    assert(tags.size == 1)
    settingsMap(tags.last)
  }

  "A thing" should behave like testSet(NormalTag)
  "A thing with special settings" should behave like testSet(SpecialTag)

  def testSet(t: Tag) {
    it should "test something" taggedAs t in {
      // ...
    }

    it should "test something else" taggedAs t in {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might be able to get the result you are after by subclassing a base test class, overriding `retrieveSettings` as appropriate.